# create django models using HTML form

Tags: django, web-applications, builder

i am working with django and trying to build a web app builder with pure django and grapesjs and django-tenant. i am wondering how to let the customer create his own database models separate from other customers and link these fields with django model in grapesjs.

Models.py
""""

""""

Comment: You probably won't want to let your users create real models... that's a recipe for disaster. Instead, you'll probably have to come up with some kind of "meta model" along the lines of arbitrary key value pairs. In any case, this is far too broad and too opinion-based to be on-topic here.